# Perl- selenium setup in Eclipse

Tags: perl, selenium

I am new to Selenium. I wanted to integrate the selenium .jar files of Perl in Eclipse. I am using EPIC editor for Perl scripting.

Selenium CPAN link: http://search.cpan.org/~gempesaw/Selenium-Remote-Driver/lib/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm

I wanted to import the downloaded Selenium jar file from the above location to Eclipse for automation. In Java, we have the option "Add External JARS" in Properties of that project.

Is there a similar option for Perl as well or let me know the other way for Perl- selenium setup in Eclipse.

Kindly let me on this. Thanks!

Comment: Any update for the above question?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Perl script to invoke the Selenium Standalone server and call this Perl script before running your automated test suite. You could also check the port 4444 (whatever port you usually run webdriver on) before executing the script to see if the webdriver is already running.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Padre IDE which includes Stawberry perl, C libraries and basic modules to start coding in perl language. Refer the link
padre.perlide.org/download